# mongoose filter based on related table

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have developed a simple schema with 2 Tables Roles and Users. The users table references the role table.

I want to select all users which have a specific role.

Towards this I have written this code

### models.js

```
var RoleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    rolename : {type: String, required: true}
});
var RoleModel = db.model('Role', RoleSchema, 'Role');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username : {type: String, required: true},
    email : {type: String, required: true},
    role : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Role', required: true}
});
var UserModel = db.model('User', UserSchema, 'User');
module.exports = {Role: RoleModel, User: UserModel};
```

### app.js

```
var models = require('../models.js);

var rolename = req.params.rolename;
logger.info('came inside getUserByRole ' + rolename);
models.User 
.where('role.rolename').equals(rolename)    
.exec(function(err, users){
    if (err) res.json(501, 'Internal Error');
    if (users == null) res.json(404, 'No users found');
    res.json(200, users);
});
```

But this code returns all the users. my hope was that the user list will be filtered by the role name which I have specified.

I also tried

```
exports.getUsersByRole = function(req, res) {   
    var rolename = req.params.rolename;
    logger.info('came inside getUserByRole ' + rolename);
    models.User 
    .find({})
    .populate({
        path: 'role',
        match: {'role.rolename': rolename}
    })
    .exec(function(err, users){
        if (err) res.json(501, 'Internal Error');
        if (users == null) res.json(404, 'No users found');
        res.json(200, users);
    });
};
```

But this also returns all the users (and the role null). does not filter on rolename and does not populate the rolename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `role` is a reference, you'll need to `populate` as you've done in the second try.  But this `populate` won't occur until the query is complete, so you'll need to filter after the initial query ([similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418489)).

So in your scenario, something like this:

```
models.User.find().populate("role").exec(function(err, users) {
    users = users.filter(function(user) {
        return user.role.rolename === req.params.rolename;
    });

    res.send(users);
});
```

Comment: does this mean that mongo will return all the records and the filtering is being done in the code (in the memory of node)?

In a relational world ... I could have filtered the record in the db itself rather than bring everything on the server and then filtering there.

Please correct me if I am wrong... I am quite new to this.

Comment: Yes, doing this will load all users, then you filter out only those than contain this specific `rolename`. And you're right, this isn't very efficient. These problems come up when you try to isolate these things into separate collections, when in a non-relational database world this might not be the best approach. You might want to consider storing the `rolename` within the `UserSchema` which will make your query faster.  Here's another stack overflow post that might be helpful in understanding this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572854/mongodb-query-on-populated-fields