# How to define a single reference schema using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new in **node.js** and **mongodb** and as in the below code i define a reference in table employee of department but here when I insert or get data from employee table i always get in array format but i want to define reference as **single column not multiple**.

```
var employee = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    dept: [department]
});

var department = new mongoose.Schema({
     dept_name : String,
     dept_code : String
})
```

I want data in response from employee table in format `{"name":"CS",dept:{"id":_id_of_dept}}

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only nest using references or arrays, so in this example, you can either create a `department` record and reference that in the `employee` document, or have an array of `department`s for the `employee` (which I understand is not what you want to do).

To reference the `department` document from your `employee` you would use something like:

```
var department = new mongoose.Schema({
    dept_name : String,
    dept_code : String
});

mongoose.model('Department', department);

var employee = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    dept: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Department' }
});
```

However, then you'll need to [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) when querying your `employee` to gather the `department` data.

But at a high level, looking at what you're trying to accomplish, I'd suggest just directly storing the `department` within the `employee` document.  Relational databases may often end up with patterns like you've described above, but in document based databases, there's really not a good reason to separate out the `department` from the `employee`.  Doing something like what I've put below will help you in the future for queries and general access of the data:

```
var employee = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    dept: {
        dept_name : String,
        dept_code : String
    }
});
```

[This answer might be helpful in understanding what I mean.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19573874/3666800)

Comment: thanks @dylants for the non-relation schema of mongodb. But I require it in my app. If I change my schemas as you suggested but there is some problem while i am populating department fields. It says that the  reference is not recognised but when i changed the reference as in the above example of mine it(within []). It work fine. But I don't want in multiple form.