# mongoosejs query on multiple referenced fields with populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, datatables, mongoose-populate

I am using **mongoosejs** with **nodejs** and **express** and I am facing a issue with search on multiple referenced fields.

I have three schema as below.

```
var CompanySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: "String"},
    category: {type:"String", ref: "CompanyCategory"},
    _id: {type: "String"},
    companyProfile: {
      logo: {type:"String"},
      address: {type:"String"},
      website: {type:"String"},
      email: {type: "String"},
      ceo: {type:"String"}
    }
    ......
```

**Employee**

```
 var EmployeeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: { type: "String" },
        company: {type: "String", required:true, ref: "Company"},
        contact: {
          address: {type: "String"},
          phone: [],
          website: {type: "String"}
        }
        .......
    });
```

**Events**

```
var EventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        title: {type: String},

        company: {type: "String", required:true, ref: "Company"},
        contactPerson: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Employee"},

        category: {type: "String", required:true},
        date: {type: "Date"},
        agenda: {type: "String"},
        ......
   });
```

I am using JQuery Datables (https://datatables.net/) and **need to implement one input search feature** (example: **https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html**) for event listing page. I spent lot of time searching for the solution with no luck. Most answers poing to **Query conditions on populate** but I need **$or conditions on result after populate**.

Something like below that works on schema without references:

```
if ( req.query.search.value ){
  var searchValue = req.query.search.value;
  query.$or = [
    { company.name: new RegExp(searchValue , 'i') },
    { contactPerson.name: new RegExp(searchValue, 'i') },
    { status: new RegExp(searchValue, 'i') },
    { venue: new RegExp(searchValue, 'i') },
    { agenda: new RegExp(searchValue, 'i') }
  ];
}
```

Is there any nice and efficient solution or do I need to change schema? I thought of **embeded schema**, but If a employee changes his details like name then I need to update changes in all embeded schemas and employee, company are referenced in most of collections.

`company.name` and `contactPerson.name` are results after populate. I tried `populate().find() , populate().where()` but nothing seems to work. Any help and direction would be helpful. Thank You.

Comment: I'm afraid that what you trying is impossible. The simplest solution to get desired results is to do three queries. First do `Company.find(name: new RegExp(searchValue , 'i'))...` if you don't get any result do `Employee.find(name: new RegExp(searchValue , 'i'))...` now if you still  get no result use your `query.$or` without  *company.name* and *contactPerson.name*. Also this might be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/a/19573874/3284355

Comment: @Molda Thank you for your response. If I normalize the data, the events will have old data if employee or company profile is changed. Is it efficient to embed and sync it if company or employee profile is changed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *if I normalise data, the events will have old data...*  also since company.name and contactPerson.name are unlikely to change too often it seems like a good idea to embed them into events. It would improve performance a lot.

Comment: @Molda Thank you, I have changed schema and kept reference as id and  also included name in events.