# How to query records in mongoose with schema having compound index with normal field and referenced field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, nestjs, compound-index

I have a Student Schema defined using mongoose. To create a primary key with both name and subject field, i have created a compound index with **name** and **subject** field.

```
@Schema()
export class Student {

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true, unique: false })
  name: string;

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'subject',
    unique: false,
  })
  subject: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  subjectTeacher: string;

}

export const StudentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(
  Student,
).index({ name: 1, subject: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

**To query the record from the collection with both fields of a primary key, i am writing the below query but unable to fetch data, can somebody please help me with this?**

```
const records  = await this.studentModel.find({name: "Joy", subject: "Maths"});

console.log(records);  // null
```

Answer (score 0):

type of subject defined as ObjectId, subject "Maths" is an object id?

Comment: I tried with ObjectId as well, but didn't worked

Comment: can you share some records?

Comment: Student:
`{
 "_id" : ObjectId("63gd1dc708c35fd11431e87d"),
 "name" : "Joy",
 "subject" : ObjectId("63gd1dc808c35hfgr3455e67l"),
 "subjectTeacher" : "John",
 "__v" : 0
}`
Subject:
`{
       "_id" : ObjectId("63gd1dc808c35hfgr3455e67l"),
       "subjectName" : "Maths",
       "__v" : 0
}`

Comment: to query that, first you should find your Maths Id and instead of searching by it name, you should search by the ID. or use embedded object. its good to check this one too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572854/mongodb-query-on-populated-fields

`const records  = await this.studentModel.find({name: "Joy", subject: "63gd1dc808c35hfgr3455e67l"}); `
and this one must give you result.

Comment: tried this also, but still not working